# Pygame - Cursor size and color, Resizable screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a program with a pygame display screen and I would like to know how to make the screen resizable. I would also want to know how to change the color and size of the cursor on the pygame screen. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking multiple questions in the same question, and that is not allowed here. Please, ask separate questions if you need.

Use `set_mode` to have a resizable window:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500), 
    pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

Then, every time it is resized, you will get an event of type `VIDEORESIZE` - use it to redraw your game elements on the new size.

To change your cursor, use `pygame.mouse.set_cursor`:

```
pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.diamond)
```

You can use the predefined cursors or load a new one from file/string. See the [module documentation here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cursors.html).

The pygame mouse cursors all have no color but a mask instead, and no way to resize. If you need more than that, consider hiding the cursor and drawing a sprite at the cursor position instead - that will make you able to do anything.